# How to remove focus of v-input-field after appended icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following form that includes rules for validation. However after I click the button and run my code which resets the input field and the validation the input field is still in focus so if I click out of it by the nature of vuetify form validation the rule of not being empty is violated. Is there not a way to just unfocus on the input box after running submit function?

```
        <v-form ref="sidebarSearchForm" lazy-validation v-on:submit.prevent>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <v-text-field label="Search"
                      single-line
                      filled
                      rounded
                      dense
                      append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                      v-model="mmcid"
                      :rules="IDRules"
                      @@click:append="searchID"
                      v-bind="{error: !validationProp,...(!validationProp && { 'error-messages': ['ID not found!'] })}"></v-text-field>
    </v-form>
```

My rules are as follows:

```
                IDRules: [
                v => !!v || 'ID is required',
                v => /^([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{0,8}$|^\d{0,8}$)/.test(v) || 'MMCID is invalid'
            ],
```

Comment: can you add searchId method in question .

Comment: are yoy looking for [this](https://codepen.io/nileshku123132522/pen/poVaYrX?editors=101)

Comment: @Nilesh Mishra not sure why that works but it does.

Comment: is it working?should i put this in answer?